# Convert Code Snippet in C# to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I want this code in VB.NET I can't convert it...

Code1

```
Response.Redirect("user.aspx?val=" + txtBox.Text);
string strVal = Request.QueryString["val"];
```

Code2

```
Session["val"] = txtBox.Text;
Response.Redirect("user.aspx");
String strVal = (string) Session["val"];
```

Comment: check this link.<br>
[http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your translation:

```vb
Response.Redirect("user.aspx?val=" & txtBox.Text)

Dim strVal As String = Request.QueryString("val")
```

and

```vb
Session("val") = txtBox.Text
Response.Redirect("user.aspx")

Dim strVal As String = DirectCast(Session("val"), String)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code1:

```
Response.Redirect("user.aspx?val=" & txtBox.Text)


Dim strVal As String
strVal=Request.QueryString("val")
```

Code2:

```
Session("val)=txtBox.Text
Response.Redirect("user.aspx")


Dim strVal As String
strVal=Cstr(Session("val"))
```